# Inner join with count() on two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like this:

```
ideas
------------ 
id 
title 
description
```

and

```
votes
------------ 
id 
ideas_id
```

And i want to make a select to get the final result of the vote, sorted. Each vote represents a point.

I tried:

> SELECT count(distinct votes.ideas_id), ideas.title,
>   ideas.description FROM votes  INNER JOIN ideas ON
>   votes.ideas_id=ideas.id

Comment: You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.  Why doesn't your query do what you intend?

Comment: It gives me the score for only one idea. I want the whole ranking.

Comment: @meska I have posted the solution but I am not sure about it until you post sample data and schema using sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 select ideas_id,vote_count,title,description 
 from  ideas inner join 
 (select count(ideas_id) as vote_count,ideas_id from votes group by ideas_id) as T
  ON T.ideas_id=ideas.id
  ORDER BY vote_count desc
```